# Can I bring a prescribed Schedule V drug into US?

Tags: usa, drugs

I live in the U.S. under a F-1 visa, and I have a bad sciatica.  When I returned home (Japan), I saw a doctor, who prescribed pregabalin, which is classified in the U.S. under Schedule V.  I will return back to the U.S. in three days, when I will have two weeks' worth of the drug.  How can I bring the medicine back there?  Can I do so at all?

Answer (score 3):

**Q.** [Can we carry medicines to USA](https://www.fda.gov/ForConsumers/ConsumerUpdates/ucm484154.htm)?

> **A:** When you come to the United States with medications, you fall under the authority of FDA, U.S. Customs and Border Protection (CBP)
>   and the Transportation Security Administration (TSA) agents operating
>   the nation's airports. ... A rule of thumb: **Bring no more than a
>   90-day supply of medication**.

Comment: I would add ... original packaging. If there isn't a pharmacy label on a bottle, bring the prescription with you.